# Implementation for dynamic graph algorithm that keeps the number of connected components of a graph after deleting edges

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have a graph, for which I want to get the number of connected components. This is easily done with a BFS or DFS traversal. But afterwards, I will iteratively be deleting some edge of the graph and ask again for the number of connected components in the resulting graph.

A simplified example of use would be:

```
graph G = some_graph();
while (some_condition) {
    cout << connected_components(G);
    edge e = some_edge_of(G);
    G.delete(e);
}
```

I have already found several dynamic graph algorithms that deal with this topic (using data structures that allow a faster re-computation of the number of connected components than doing another traversal of the graph).

But could you save me some time implementing them and provide me a link to some free implementation? (Preferably in C or C++)

Comment: Four years later, did you succeed in implementing it?

Answer (score -1):

[Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/) has what you are looking for,
although from my point of view the learning curve is quite steep...

There is [a book](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Boost-Graph-Library/Jeremy-G-Siek/e/9780201729146) about it.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not find it there. There are dynamic algorithms in the case that the graph is updated by [adding edges](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/incremental_components.html), but not for removing edges. In  the case of incremental updates, a MF-SET does the trick.